# Problem when enabling Mongodb

Tags: 8, database

I get an error after enabling mongodb module in Drupal 8. I am using Drupal 8.1.3 and MongoDB 8.x-1.x-dev.

I get the following error:

> Argument 1 passed to `Drupal\\mongodb\\MongoCollectionFactory::__construct()` must be of the type array, object given, called in /var/www/html/d/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php on line 268 and defined in /var/www/html/d/modules/contrib/mongodb/src/MongoCollectionFactory.php on line 48, referer: http://localhost/d/admin/modules

I followed all the steps in README.txt. What is causing the error?